# Gysin homomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Le $M$ be smooth, compact and oriented manifold, $\quad \partial M= X\times F$, where $F, X\quad$are compact smooth and oriented manifold. We comsider the pojection $\pi : \partial M\longrightarrow X$ with fiber $F$. My question is how are define the Gysin maps in homology and cohomology:
$$\pi^{*} : C_{k}(X)\longrightarrow C_{k+\nu}(\partial M),\quad \dim F=\nu$$
and $$\pi_{*} : C^{k}(\partial M)\longrightarrow C^{k-\nu}(X)$$

Comment: Cross with the class of the fiber and integrate over the fiber.

Comment: I don't quiet understand. Could you write it please!

Comment: Ted Shifrin, here we are in singular cohomology, so I don't understand why should I integrate over the fiber $F$. Could you be more clear please

Comment: You have provided no framework for your question; nor have you indicated your level of knowledge. What you need is *cup* product with the fundamental class $[F]$ for the first map and *cap* product with it for the second map.

Comment: I am new about this field. Could you suggest me any book where I can learn more about Gysin map and cup product?

Comment: This is standard algebraic topology material, but algebraic topology has a steep learning curve. You need to learn Poincaré duality, as well. The modern source most people look at is Hatcher's text (which is available, free, in pdf form as well as in published textbook form).

Comment: Thanks very much! But If i understood well, the second map has to be defined as follow $$\pi_{*}(c)=c\frown [F] ?$$

Comment: Yes, that's right. And if you represent cohomology by differential forms, you literally integrate over the fiber. This works for fiber bundles, in general. You can think of the Gysin map as Poincaré dual to $\pi_*: H_{k-\nu}(X\times F)\to  H_{k-\nu}(X)$.

Comment: The cap product $c\frown [F]$ souldnt be element of $H_{k-\nu}(X)$? On the second map, I have codomain $C^{k-\nu}$. I remember that in the Poincare duality the cap product product is element in Homology class and not not cohomology class. In my case here I want $\pi_{*}([c])$ be element of  $H^{k-\nu}(X)$